How can I add an external antenna to a GooSKY S1 mini helicopter flight controller?
I recently purchased the GooSKY S1 mini helicopter flight controller with a receiver that has an internal antenna, as shown in the picture below:

I have limited knowledge of RF and I’m unsure whether adding an external antenna would improve the range. I’ve come across some sources suggesting that it could, but I want to be sure before making any modifications.
Is there a recommended method for adding an external antenna, other than simply soldering a wire to the existing antenna or to any exposed pads on the PCB? Would such a modification potentially improve performance, or is there a better approach to achieve a more stable and longer-range signal?
